# Mysql group by two columns and pick the maximum value of third column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table that has user_id, item_id and interaction_type as columns. interaction_type could be 0, 1,2,3,4 or 5. However, for some user_id and item_id pairs, we might have multiple interaction_types. For example, we might have:

```
user_id   item_id    interaction_type
2            3            1
2            3            0
2            3            5
4            1            0
5            4            4
5            4            2
```

What I want is to only keep the maximum interaction_type if there are multiples. So I want this:

```
user_id   item_id    interaction_type
2            3            5
4            1            0
5            4            4
```

Here is the query I wrote for this purpose:

```
select user_id, item_id, max(interaction_type) as max_type
from mytable
group by user_id, item_id;
```

But the result is weird. For example, in the original table I have 100000 rows with interaction_type=5 but in the result table I have only 2000. How is this possible as the max will pick 5 between every comparison that contains 5 and therefore I shouldn't have fewer 5 in the result table.

Comment: Add some more rows with sample data, with different values in all column, and adjust the expected result.

Comment: Are you sure that each set of `user_id`, `item_id`, `interaction_type` is unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine.  The reason you are getting 2000 rows is because you are getting one row for every unique pair of values `user_id`, `item_id`.

If you want to see the interaction types going into each row then use:

```
select user_id, item_id, max(interaction_type) as max_type,
       group_concat(distinct interaction_type) as interaction_types,
       count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by user_id, item_id;
```

It occurs to me that you want all rows with the maximum interaction type.  If so, calculate the maximum and then find all rows that match that value:

```
select t.*
from mytable t cross join
     (select max(interaction_type) as maxit from mytable) x
     on x.maxit = t.interaction_type;
```

No `group by` is needed for this query.

Comment: No I don't want all rows with maximum interaction type. I want the max of those that we have more than one interaction type for the same user and item.

Comment: So basically what I want is to get rid of the duplicate interaction types when the user_id and item_id are the same for those rows. Picking max was one of the ways.

Comment: "The reason you are getting 2000 rows is because you are getting one row for every unique pair of values of user_id and item_id". I don't think so. Because I guess I should get at least 100000 rows with interaction_type=5 as 5 will win in every comparison so I shouldn't have fewer 5. I might have fewer 0,1,2,3,4 but not 5. Am I wrong?

Comment: @HimanAB . . . The number of rows is determined by the number of combinations of `user_id` and `item_id` in the data, not by the number of rows with `interaction_type = 5`.  You simply have duplicates.